# Magento 1.7 category attributes in frontend

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7, categories, frontend

I've created a custom attribute for categories in Magento; but oddly enough, I'm not able to grab it to the frontend. I've been trying to find a solution for this since yesterday, to no avail.

I've seen multiple threads on different forums, including SO. I've tried multiple solutions. For example:

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getAttributes()
```

And also the following:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getAttributes()
```

Which I believe does the same thing. The problem is, they both return the following error which I can't seem to figure out:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::loadAllAttributes() in
>   X:....\project\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php on line
>   289

Also, trying to var_dump getData() doesn't return this attribute, even though it (the attribute) does exist in the backend under "Manage Categories", and even though it can be modified and saved and remain the way it was  last saved when you refresh the page. I've also tried multiple solutions that suggests using a loop to loop through all categories and grab the attributes; but that didn't work either.

Printing the following:

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->debug()
```

As another thread adviced, didn't return the attribute I'd created, but it returned the default attributes.

I've checked multiple sites to ensure that I didn't miss anything critical during the creation of the attribute, and so far I've not found anything that I've missed.

When creating the attribute; the following parameters where used:

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'used_by', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Used by',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));
```

My questions are:

1. How do I grab the custom attribute that I made and use it in the
   frontend?
2. What are the parameters that *have* to be there for the attribute to
   function properly in the backend and frontend?

Comment: Did you reindex afterwards? Are you running in flat catalog mode or not? Flat catalog is highly suggested by the way.

Comment: THANK YOU! Re-indexing was the problem! If you feel like it, write an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Haha, lesson learned..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection pages in Magento use flat tables if flat catalog is switched on.

Any additional attrribute if added will not be there in flat table.

Indexing is the way to update flat tables.

So when you did re-index column for newly created attribute was added and data was populated.